# Genitive plural of "башка"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, множественное-число, родительный-падеж

What is the genitive plural and nominative plural of `башка`?

My search returned a lot of contradicting information. Is there any authoritative source with a single concrete answer?

Comment: This link may be interesting to you http://deevrod.narod.ru/think/o_boshkax.html

Comment: [The dictionary](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90._%D0%90._%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0) basically [says it all](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?word=\[bashka\]). «Р. мн. затрудн.» indeed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

башка is originally not Russian word. It comes from Turkish baš which means head. And it is really used in common language, rather than in literature.

In plural башка may have 2 valid forms: башки́ and another one that changes letter in the root to бо́шки (with accent on the о́).

In genitive those will respectively be башки́ (singular) and башо́к or бо́шек (plural). Both variants are considered valid, even though I prefer the last one :).

Comment: +1 for бошек, never heard of башок.

Comment: башка is of course an imported, and moreover a colloquial word, but could you still try to provide an authoritative source to support your answer? There are countless publications on the colloquial language and I can't believe none have addressed this question.

Comment: I think iHundter gave very good link. First plural variant comes from logical conclusion on how Russian language should be, second plural variant comes from how Russian person would actually say it :)

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich ah, logic and Russian, two great nemeses.

Comment: @kotekzot, You are absolutely right :)

Comment: Question - have you ever heard or seen `башки́` used in plural form without numerals as in `сейчас поснимаю им башки́` and not in genitive singular (as in `вон торчат две башки́`)? Are there any examples of such usage in literature?

Comment: @kotekzot Logic and any linguistics don't go together :)

Comment: Interesting how words change their meaning across languages. The same word բաշ (баш) means mane (грива) in Armenian.

Comment: @AleksG wrong. Logic and linguistics do go together. As for the question - formally both paradigms answer to "how Russian language should be", it's Zaliznyak's b and d paradigms, respectively (with the obvious conclusion that phonemically башка is бошка).

Answer (score 3):

Nominative plural is *башки*.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) says the genitive plural is *башок*.
Yet I've never heard this word. Usually, one would find a synonym in this case.

Comment: Wiktionary isn't the best source about slang.

Comment: @Nakilon Wiktionary is much better about slang than many dictionaries :). I'm a native Russian speaker, and I have never heard plural genitive form of `башка` used.

Comment: «бо́шки поотрываю!»

Comment: бо́шек is the correct form, -1

Comment: @Anixx Give the link confiming бошек is the correct form. Lingvo agrees with Wiktionary.

Answer (score 2):

Nominative: бОшки
Genitive: бОшек

The stress is on the second syllable. That is what I use.

It is very informal, by the way. I guess you know. :)

Comment: Did you want to say the stress on the FIRST syllable?

Comment: The word бо́шки is mostly used as a name of marijuana.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the correct original spelling of this word borrowed from a Turkic (?Tatar) language is *"башка"*. The spelling *"бошка"* may refer to northern-eastern dialects of Russian, which are located closer to the modern area of the Tatar language. The northern dialects tend to pronounce unstressed "a" as "o" (sorry for the absence of phonetic signs). 
That's why we can consider Genitive Plural *"бОшек"* as the form of *"бошка"* (where shift of accent is another question), and G. Pl. *"башОк"* as the one of *"башка"* (the same model кишок - кишка). Though the word *"башок"* is surely extinct in the modern language.
So, I think, we can't talk about the form G. Pl. of *"башка"* at all, and such pair as *"башкА" - "бОшек"* is only reconsideration of paradigm because of the absence of *"башок"*.

offtopic: It is interesting, that, according to the research of Vladimir Belikov, Acc.Sg. *"башкУ"* is more frequently used by male respondents, while *"бОшку"* is more popular with the female:)

Answer (score 1):

"бОшки" пожалуй корректнее. 
Например "бестолковые бОшки". бывают в разговорной речи и "глупые башкИ", но реже.
можно и башОк.
"гатожь - связка рыбы в дюжину башок"
Также:
"бОшки поотрываю"
"стукнулись башкАми"
И - можно и "глупым башкАм" и "глупым бОшкам".

Answer (score 0):

The correct is бОшки with stress on о. бОшки also found in smoker's slang. This term extensively used to name top part of weed.

Genitive plural is бОшек.

Посмотри, каких я амстердамских бошек притащил!